# Silverstripe 3.1.2 Issue saving FocusPoint when module used with Gallery module

Tags: image, gallery, crop, silverstripe

I'm using two great modules for Silverstripe 3 but there is a conflict somewhere which I can't work out. I've asked the developers but they have not found the solution yet.

Modules:
FocusPoint which allows you to choose where the image crops from. Great!
https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-focuspoint

Gallery, popular gallery module.
https://github.com/frankmullenger/silverstripe-gallery

Both work fine. But Focus points do not "save" within the gallery section of a Gallery page. You can edit and choose the focus point but after saving it snaps back to the previous position. You can alter the focus point in the Files tab of the CMS so it must be how Gallery saves each image.
I have updated the template to CroppedFocusedImage but this is not a template issue.

It would be a very helpful addition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide some details of failure? Do you see any warning or error messages if you run in dev mode? Any small black error box on left-top when you save?

If FocusPoint module does not work, you can have a look at folder permissions or maybe any PHP libraries like ImageMagick, GD support etc. Maybe you you changed something during upgrade?

If both modules work individually, but the problem is cropped image is not saved in correct directory, it is another issue although it could still be permission issue.

You can set which folder it needs to save into, same as how you set in normal UploadField. But it wouldn't change just because of your upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer it has been resolved here: https://github.com/frankmullenger/silverstripe-gallery/pull/23